# Getting the error "nodename nor servname provided, or not known" (client server application)

Tags: c, sockets, pipe, client-server

I have created a client and server in C, the code is perfect and has been reviewed many times (my professor gave it to me). However whenever I try to execute it, by doing:

```
./client server 50000
```

(specifying hostname `server` and port 50000), I get the error message:

```
Error in the name resolution: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening; I am currently running this on my Mac with M1.

Please find here attached the server in C:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define BUFSIZE 4096

const char *service = "50000";

void handler(int sign){

    int status;

    (void)sign;

    while(waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG) > 0){
        continue;
    }
}


int main(){

    int cc, err, on, sd;
    struct addrinfo hints, *res;
    struct sigaction sa;

    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    sa.sa_handler = handler;

    if(sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1){
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(&hints,0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    err = getaddrinfo(stderr,service, &hints, &res);
    if(err != 0){
        fprintf(stderr,"Gai error: %s\n",gai_strerror(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    sd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype,res->ai_protocol);
    if(sd < 0){
        perror("socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    on = 1;
    if(setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,&on, sizeof(on)) < 0){
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cc = bind(sd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
    if(cc < 0){
        perror("bind");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    cc = listen(sd, SOMAXCONN);
    if(cc < 0){
        perror("listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for(;;){
        int pid, ns;

        ns = accept(sd, NULL, NULL);
        if(ns < 0){

            if(errno == EINTR){
                continue;
            }
            perror("accept");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        pid = fork();
        if(pid < 0){
            perror("fork");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }else if (pid == 0){

            /*SON*/

            char year[BUFSIZE];
            char number[BUFSIZE];
            char type[BUFSIZE];
            const char *ack = "ACK\n";
            int pid_n1, pid_n2;
            int pipe_n1n2[2], pipe_n2f[2];

            close(sd);

            memset(year, 0, sizeof(year));
            cc = read(ns, year, sizeof(year) - 1);
            if(cc < 0){
                perror("read");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            cc = write(ns, ack, strlen(ack));
            if(cc < 0){
                perror("write");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            memset(number,0, sizeof(number));
            cc = read(ns, number, sizeof(number) - 1);
            if(cc < 0){
                perror("read");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            cc = write(ns, ack, strlen(ack));
            if(cc < 0){
                perror("write");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            memset(type, 0, sizeof(type));
            cc = read(ns, type, sizeof(type) -1);
            if(cc < 0){
                perror("read");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            cc = pipe(pipe_n1n2);
            if(cc < 0){
                perror("pipe");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            pid_n1 = fork();
            if(pid_n1 < 0){
                perror("fork");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }else if (pid_n1 == 0){
                /*NEPHEW 1*/
                char db_file[BUFSIZE];

                close(ns);
                close(pipe_n1n2[0]);
                close(1);
                dup(pipe_n1n2[1]);
                close(pipe_n1n2[1]);

                snprintf(db_file,sizeof(db_file),"/var/local/games/%s/%s.txt",year,type);
                execlp("sort","sort","-n","-r",db_file,NULL);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            cc = pipe(pipe_n2f);
            if(cc < 0){
                perror("pipe");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            pid_n2 = fork();
            if(pid_n2 < 0){
                perror("fork");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }else if (pid_n2 == 0){
                /*NEPHEW 2*/
                close(ns);

                close(pipe_n1n2[1]);
                close(0);
                dup(pipe_n1n2[0]);
                close(pipe_n1n2[0]);

                close(pipe_n2f[0]);
                close(1);
                dup(pipe_n2f[1]);
                close(pipe_n2f[1]);

                execlp("cut","cut","-f","1,4",NULL);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            /*SON*/
            close(pipe_n1n2[0]);
            close(pipe_n1n2[1]);

            close(pipe_n2f[1]);
            close(0);
            dup(pipe_n2f[0]);
            close(pipe_n2f[0]);

            close(1);
            dup(ns);
            close(ns);

            execlp("head","head","-n",number,NULL);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        }
        close(ns);
    }
    close(sd);
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the client in C:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFSIZE 4096

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int err;
    struct addrinfo hints, *res;
    char *remote_host, remote_service;
    char year[BUFSIZE];
    char number[BUFSIZE];
    char type[BUFSIZE];

    if(argc < 3){
        fprintf(stderr,"Wrong use: client server port");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(&hints,0,sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    remote_host = argv[1];
    remote_service = argv[2];

    if((err = getaddrinfo(remote_host,remote_service,&hints,&res)) != 0){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error in the name resolution: %s\n",gai_strerror(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Insert the year of publication:\n");
    scanf("%s",year);

    do{
        int cc, sd, i = 0;
        struct addrinfo *ptr;
        uint8_t buffer[BUFSIZE];

        printf("Insert the number of games:\n");
        scanf("%s",number);

        printf("Insert the type:\n");
        scanf("%s",type);

        for(ptr = res; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next){
            if((sd = socket(ptr->ai_family,ptr->ai_socktype,ptr->ai_protocol)) < 0){
                fprintf(stderr,"Error in socket creation");
                continue;
            }

            if(connect(sd,ptr->ai_addr,ptr->ai_addrlen) == 0){
                fprintf(stderr,"Successful connection: %d\n",i);
                break;
            }

            close(sd);
            i++;
        }

        if(ptr == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr,"Couln't find the corresponding address");
            exit(3);
        }

        if(write(sd,year,strlen(year)) < 0){
            perror("error writing year");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if(read(sd,buffer,sizeof(buffer)) < 0){
            perror("error reading ack (year)");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if(write(sd,number,strlen(number)) < 0){
            perror("error writing number");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if(read(sd,buffer,sizeof(buffer)) < 0){
            perror("error reading ack (number)");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if(write(sd,type,strlen(type)) < 0){
            perror("error writing type");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        while((cc = read(sd,buffer,sizeof(buffer)) > 0)){
            write(1,buffer,cc);
        }

        if(cc < 0){
            perror("error reading result in the server ");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        close(sd);

        printf("Insert the year (end for terminating):\n");
        scanf("%s",year);
    }while(strcmp(year,"end") != 0);

    freeaddrinfo(res);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: AFAICS, the code doesn't contain the error message you claim you see.  That suggests that you aren't running the code produced from this source.  I'm code viewing on a cell phone so I may have missed something, and there's an outside chance that the message corresponds to a system error (but the “or” clause, and missing prefix, make that unlikely).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for your answer, didn't really understood your reply. Any idea on how I can fix this?

Comment: Now I'm using a browser on a large screen, I can confirm that `servname` does not appear in any of the system error messages on macOS (Big Sur 11.7.1), nor does the message appear in any of the code you showed in the question.  Consequently, the error you see is not produced by the code you show.  This means that you must either be running some other code instead of what you show, or you must have some auxilliary code that's called from within this code that reports the error.  So, you must review how you compiled this code, and how you run it.  There is nothing we can do to help you.

Comment: In my first long comment, I was not able to check system error messages because I was using a cell phone, not a laptop or desktop. However, the message doesn't quite conform to the usual way system error messages are written. Furthermore, the majority of the error messages in the code are produced by calling `perror("function");` (for different values of the string), and `perror()` puts out that string followed by a system error.  The message quoted doesn't have a prefix like that. So, I'm claiming that the information in the question is incomplete — it doesn't show what generates the error.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I went over the code and I have realised that the error is generated by this if statement in the client section:
`if((err = getaddrinfo(remote_host,remote_service,&hints,&res)) != 0){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error in the name resolution: %s\n",gai_strerror(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }`

Comment: So, the error message is actually `Error in the name resolution: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`.  Missing out half of the error message leads to confusion.  So, now you need to track down what information you're providing to the program (and hence to `getaddrinfo()`) as the server name.  Using `server` rather than `mickey-mouse.example.com` (or perhaps just `mickey-mouse`) isn't working; you need to specify the machine that is running the server.  You may be able to use `localhost` if the server program is running on the same machine as you're testing the client on.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I did try to use localhost, the program indeed starts, however it blocks itself after basically inserting the 3 inputs.

Comment: Note that your `scanf()` statements in `client.c` are incorrect.  You have: `scanf("%s",year);` but you need `scanf("%s", &year);` and similarly with other examples.  I dispute that the code is perfect.

Comment: That is an improvement — you now have a different problem: _after basically inserting the 3 inputs._. That is most likely because the server isn't running and listening on port 50000.  I don't see evidence of the server program daemonizing itself, so you'll need to run `./server &`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler As a matter of fact the scanf is actually wrong, good that you actually spotted it! Thank you !

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Update, just tried with ./server & and basically the server is listening on the port 11173. So I changed the launch of my client with ./client localhost 11173, it still asks me for the 3 inputs, but after I inserted the third one the program stops with the error message "Couldn't find the corresponding address"

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I do have a bit of doubts regarding the syntax of the scanf, usually when you use `&` is when you have formats like `char *`, however in this case the scanf formats are char (*)[4096]

Comment: My bad!  It didn't occur to me that you're reading the year as a string, not a number.  That line is OK.  And I guess using a buffer of 4096 bytes is big enough to avoid overflow problems.  The code should check that a value was safely read, but there is no need for the `&` as I claimed.  You'll need to work out why the server is listening on port 11173 instead of 50000, and whether you can change that.  I saw a string `char *service = "50000";`, but I assumed that the server would listen on that port. So far, the code is OK; the problem is using it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Exactly !! I really have no clue why during the execution of it things aren't going the way they should!